# Matlab integral returning infinite not-a-number

Tags: matlab, function, infinite, integral

I'm attempting to integrate a function and keep receiving the warning:

```
Warning: Infinite or Not-a-Number value encountered.
```

I've been unable to determine why this is the case and was hoping someone may be able to shed some light. I believe one of the parameters is giving off an Inf value but I haven't been able to determine which one. Any help would be appreciated.

```
lm = 1.75; 
Cm = 3.2E6;
fe = 1380;
H = 13.5;
q = 1E-5;
Cw = 4.2E6;
y = 0.0;
x = 0.1;
ts = [0.1 97/24];           
Mt = 100; 
t = linspace(ts(1)*86400, ts(2)*86400, Mt); % [s]
QL = fe/H;                   
z = H/2;
Dt = lm/Cm;             
r = x.^2+y.^2;  
vT = q*Cw*Cm;
T = zeros(size(t));

for i = 1:length(t)
    tt = t(i);

    fun = @(ze) T_GIGF(z,ze,Dt,tt,vT,r)/sqrt(pi)./sqrt(r+(z-ze).^2);

    T(i) = QL/(4*pi*lm)*exp(vT*x/2*Dt).*...
    (integral(fun,0,H)-...
     integral(fun,-H,0));

end

function func = T_GIGF(z,ze,a,tt,VT,r)
u1 = (r+(z-ze).^2)/(4*a*tt);
u2 = VT^2*(r+(z-ze).^2)/(16*a^2);
func = 0.5*sqrt(pi)*(exp(-2*sqrt(u2)).*erfc(sqrt(u1)-sqrt(u2./u1))+...
                    exp(+2*sqrt(u2)).*erfc(sqrt(u1)+sqrt(u2./u1)));

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You getting this because your u1 and u2 are huge numbers of about 1e29!!! Thus doing exp(1e29) goes over range of what double number can support:

`exp(1e29) > realmax` results in 1